# Unexpected HTTP 403 error in Java

Tags: java, http

I am using Api in my Java App and triggering this URL (http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999). I am getting HTTP 403 error in console but in web browser no error occurs and getting the expected response. I also tried other URL and they work fine without problem or any errors.

So, what is the problem in URL and what should I do?

Here is source code :
Main.java

```
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;


public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
String numb = "9999999999,8888888888";
String response = new http_client("http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles="+numb).response;
System.out.println(response);
// encoding response 
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(response);
JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;
String msg = (String) jObj.get("msg");
System.out.println("MESSAGE : "+msg);
JSONObject msg_text = (JSONObject) jObj.get("msg_text");

String[] numbers = numb.split(",");
for(String number : numbers)
{
if(number.length() != 10 || number.matches(".*[A-Za-z].*")){
System.out.println(number+" is invalid.");
}else{
if(msg_text.get(number).equals("Y"))
{
System.out.println(number+" is DND Activated.");
}else{
System.out.println(number+" is not DND Activated.");
}
}
}
}
}
```

Now , http_client.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class http_client
{
   String response = "";
http_client(String URL) throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader bs = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String data ="";
    String response = "";
    while((data = bs.readLine()) != null){
        response = response + data;
    }
    con.disconnect();
    url = null;
    con = null;
    this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Comment: 403 means Forbidden, maybe the API needs some privileges to be adjusted before acceding it from a Java application.

Comment: @Oussama browser doesn't return any error.

Comment: Please read again my comment "adjusted before acceding it from a Java application"

Comment: Why don't you show the code?

Comment: It's Java Swing Code, but currently in my computer, will post the code tomorrow. One thing I noticed that my Android Tablet doesn't showing any error (I am using AIDE there) and my PC shows HTTP 403 error for the same code(I am using NetBeans IDE there). Thanks

Comment: @Cássio Mazzochi Molin added the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you showing us the code you're using to access the supplied URL (`http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999`) it makes it a wee bit difficult to determine exactly where your problem lies but my first guess would be that the link you provided is only accessible through a **Secure Socket Layer** (SSL). In other words, the link should start with **https://** instead of **http://**

To validate this simply make the change to your url string: `https://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999` and try again.

You're not going to have an issue with a browser for the simple reason that generally browsers will always try both protocols to make a connection. It is also up to the Website what protocol is acceptable, lots allow for both and some just don't.

To check if a url string is utilizing a valid protocol you can use this little method I quickly whipped up:

```
/**
 * This method will take the supplied URL String regardless of the protocol (http or https)
 * specified at the beginning of the string, and will return whether or not it is an actual
 * "http" (no SSL) or "https" (is SSL) protocol. A connection to the URL is attempted first 
 * with the http protocol and if successful (by way of data acquisition) will then return 
 * that protocol. If not however, then the https protocol is attempted and if successful then 
 * that protocol is returned. If neither protocols were successful then Null is returned.<br><br>
 * 
 * Returns null if the supplied URL String is invalid, a protocol does not
 * exist, or a valid connection to the URL can not be established.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param webLink (String) The full link path.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) Either "http" for Non SLL link, "https" for a SSL link. 
 * Null is returned if the supplied URL String is invalid, a protocol does 
 * not exist, or a valid connection to the URL can not be established.
 */
public static String isHttpOrHttps(String webLink) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(webLink);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { return null; }

    String protocol = url.getProtocol();
    if (protocol.equals("")) { return null; }

        URLConnection yc;
        try {
            yc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            in.close();
            return "http";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do nothing....check for https instead.
        }
        try {
            yc = new URL(webLink).openConnection();
            //send request for page data...
            yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
            yc.connect();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            in.close();
            return "https";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do Nothing....allow for Null to be returned.
        }
    return null;
}
```

To use this method:

```
// Note that the http protocol is supplied within the url string:
String protocol = isHttpOrHttps("http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999");
System.out.println(protocol);
```

The output to console will be: `https`. The ***isHttpOrHttps()*** method has determined that the **https** protocol is the successful protocol to use in order to acquire data (or whatever) even though **http** was supplied.

To pull the page source from the web page you can perhaps use a method like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a List ArrayList containing the page source for the supplied web 
 * page link.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param link (String) The URL address of the web page to process.<br>
 * 
 * @return (List ArrayList) A List ArrayList containing the page source for 
 * the supplied web page link.
 */
public static List<String> getWebPageSource(String link) {
    if (link.equals("")) { return null; }
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);

        URLConnection yc = null;
        //If url is a SSL Endpoint (using a Secure Socket Layer such as https)...
        if (link.startsWith("https:")) {
            yc = new URL(link).openConnection();
            //send request for page data...
            yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
            yc.connect();
        }
        //and if not a SLL Endpoint (just http)...
        else { yc = url.openConnection(); }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        List<String> sourceText = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            sourceText.add(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        return sourceText;
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) { 
        // Do whatever you want with exception.
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) { 
        // Do whatever you want with exception.
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In order to utilize both the methods supplied here you can try something like this:

```
String netLink = "http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999";
String protocol = isHttpOrHttps(netLink);
String netLinkProtocol = netLink.substring(0, netLink.indexOf(":"));
if (!netLinkProtocol.equals(protocol)) {
    netLink = protocol + netLink.substring(netLink.indexOf(":"));
}
List<String> list = getWebPageSource(netLink);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

And the console output will display:

```
{"msg":"success","msg_text":{"9999999999":"N"}}
```

Comment: checkout the source code. This code runs without any problem in my Android Tablet using AIDE but my PC shows HTTP 403 error for that code (I am using NetBeans IDE there).

Comment: Strange....the code works just fine on my PC also using NetBeans (jdk 1.8.x). I have tested the above code and it works fine. Maybe **checkdnd.com** kicked your PC's butt outta there. :P Try utilizing the code exactly as shown.

Comment: does above code means my code or yours. I Tigger the URL from web browser (same PC) and that doesn't show any error. So, they haven't blocked my PC or IP. One thing does it compulsory to set User-Agent, I doesn't set that in my PC also not on Tablet.

Comment: My code...Forget about yours for now. Try the code I provided on your PC and see how it works. If it works fine then implement it into your own code. The connection to the page is: **HTTPS** by the way

Comment: Thanks @DevilsHnd, now the code works for me.(Mine code) I dropped the con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0); line, which results in malfunctioning. Also your code will goona work but it triggers URL many times result in slow process, so I used and edited my code. Once again Thanks all. :-)

Comment: @VishalP - Glad it all worked out for you :) If you found my answer helpful then please up-vote it.